# Understanding the meaning of probability terms: law vs distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have been reading a paper for a while, but still get confused when the author uses the term 'law' and the term 'distribution'.

So, he literally says this: "denote by $P$ the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$, thus if we factorize the marginal law $P$ on $Y$, as..."

and another one:
"... the density of this law ... " ?? what does this mean?

So, is it that Law and distribution refer to the same? I mean a PDF?

Are there any other terms I should be familiar with so, I would be easier for me to read papers in these topics? Please, feel free to type any terms you may have found while doing your research.

I have seen that people use 'density', 'distribution'.

Comment: It may be a linguistic issue.  My impression is that "law" (or "loi") is more common among native French speakers than native English speakers, but they understand each other without ambiguity

Answer (score 2):

I often see the words "distribution" and "law" as generic terms for a description of a random variable. This can be made concrete as a CDF or (sometimes) as a PDF. Thus the law/distribution is a more abstract thing attached to the random variable whereas the CDF or PDF is a concrete representation of the information in the distribution. This is probably the sense the person meant it when they said "the density of this law."

I also often see the word "law" used a lot in a technical sense as another type of mathematical object that characterizes a distribution. Namely, the law is the probability measure induced by the random variable. For a real-valued random variable, we have a probability space $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R), \mathbb P_X)$ where $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ is the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb R$ and the law $\mathbb P_X$ is the measure such that for $A\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R),$ $$\mathbb P_X(A) = \mathbb P(X\in A).$$ It can be defined as a push-forward of the original probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb P)$ on which the random variable $X:\Omega\to \mathbb R$ is defined. In other words $ \mathbb P_X(A) = \mathbb P(X^{-1}(A)).$

Comment: Is then by the law of a random variable meant rather it's pdf, if it exists ? More precisely, let $X$ be a normal multivariate random variable, $N(\mu, \Sigma)$. We set $Y = AX + t, \,A \in \mathbb{R}^{k\times n}, t \in \mathbb{R}^k.$  I am asked to find the law of $Y.$ What is precisely meant in this context by the law ? Is it the push-forward measure or rather the pdf of $Y$ ? Thanks.

Comment: @user996159 Hard to say. I would guess they just mean any description of it… it’s MVN with some mean vector and covariance matrix that you can solve for. (Keep in mind also that MVN distribution doesn’t always have a PDF.)